# Unable to connect to Pivotal cloudfoundry from IntelliJ,

Tags: intellij-idea, cloud-foundry, pivotaltracker, intellij-14

Unable to connect to Pivotal cloudfoundry from IntelliJ,
getting the error as Cannot connect : org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I?O error on GET request for "http://api.run.pivotal.io/info": api.run.pivotal.io; nested excpetion is java.net.UnknownHostException:api.run.pivotal.io.
Has anybody tried intelliJ with pivotal Cloudfoundry
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect over https, `https://api.run.pivotal.io/info`.  Give that a try.  If you connect over http you get a 404, with https the request goes through.